# Can I delete default buckets on Google App Engine Storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

When I create a new application on Google Cloud App Engine, these buckets in Google Storage show up as well:

```
bucket_1: <region>.artifacts.<app_id>.appspot.com
bucket_2: staging.<app_id>.appspot.com
bucket_3: <app_id>.appspot.com
```

I've only added 300MB on bucket_3 and never added anything to bucket_1. Nonetheless, bucket_1 is currently occupying 3.9GB. Why do I need this bucket_1? Can I delete all its content or even delete the whole bucket?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not delete these buckets or their contents.  You will regret it if you ever need them.  I'm pretty sure Google doesn't charge you for them, because you can do a lot without even enabling billing.

Comment: @gaefan In my case, all these 3 buckets are created as Multi-Region buckets, and they do not fall under the free 5GB quota, which only applies to certain regional buckets. I have confirmed this with both billing and technical support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new App Engine Application, these buckets in Google Storage are created:

```
bucket_2: staging.<app_id>.appspot.com
bucket_3: <app_id>.appspot.com
```

Bucket `bucket_1: <region>.artifacts.<app_id>.appspot.com` is created when you run the command `gcloud app deploy`. This is the Container Registry bucket where App Engine stores container images. You can delete this bucket, however, next time when you deploy a new version `gcloud app deploy` the bucket will be recreated.

I did some testing on my side and observed that when you deploy your first app engine standard version, 48 images are created in `us.artifacts.your-project.appspot.com/containers/images` folder. From this moment, every time you deploy a new app engine version 3 more images are added to this folder. I am not sure about the internal implementation, but I think it caches the images in this folder.